# Remote management with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get some information from several machines on the network but I get loads of entries of the local machine.. for each entry in the text file I get an entry from the local machine.

Any idea where I'm going wrong.. winrm is configured on the remote machines and running.

```
$Username = Read-Host "Please enter Username"
$Password = read-host "please enter Password"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
$computers = gc c:\test\file.txt
foreach ($Computer in $computers)
{
Invoke-command -ComputerName $computers -credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'ipconfig'" | out-file c:\test\output.txt -append}
}
cls
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `Invoke-command -ComputerName $computer`..singular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are iterating one by one but you are not passing one by one to the invoke-command, $computer will have each value at a time in the foreach loop.

Instead of this:

```
foreach ($Computer in $computers)
{
Invoke-command -ComputerName $computers -credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'ipconfig'" | out-file c:\test\output.txt -append}
}
```

Do this:

```
foreach ($Computer in $computers)
{
Invoke-command -ComputerName $computer -credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'ipconfig'" | out-file c:\test\output.txt -append}
}
```

Further improvement:

You do not have to give `Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'ipconfig'"`
Instead of this,you can directly use **ipconfig** inside the scriptblock.

Comment: Hi Dutta, thanks for the quick response. I'm just getting one output with that and I don't see the difference between the two examples :(

Comment: $computer = only gives me output of local machine

Comment: Show me the file content.

Comment: The file content is...svr01.test.loc
dc01.test.loc

Comment: svr01.test.loc
dc01.test.loc

Comment: wrongly implemented. In each line , you put one server

Comment: @NorrinRad: $computer is the main thing. You have kept actually $computers in the invoke-command which is wrong . It has to iterate one by one.

Comment: @RanadipDutta you can pass an array to invoke-command so using $computers is not wrong. Using $computers within the foreach means you are executing the code against each remote computer as many times as there are entries in $computers

Comment: Yes no harm. SInce he is using Foreach, thats why i made the singular approach :)

Answer (score 1):

`Invoke-Command` will take an array for the ComputerName param so you can use `$computers` instead of using a foreach loop (assuming that you have one computer name per-line in the file).

I've also used `Get-Credential` to prompt for the full credential in one go rather than asking for username and password individually.

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$computers = Get-Content c:\test\file.txt
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'ipconfig'" | Out-File c:\test\output.txt -Append}
```

The reason you are only seeing a single computers info in `c:\test\output.txt`  is because the output of the the `ipconfig` command is being saved to the remote computer... so you will have a `c:\test\output.txt` file on each computer you run the command against.

---

**EDIT:**

To take the output of each remote command and save it to your local computer just move the `Out-File` outside the `Invoke-Command` like this:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$computers = Get-Content c:\test\file.txt
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'ipconfig'"} | Out-File c:\test\output.txt -Append
```

Comment: Thanks Dutta and James.. The $computer (singular) thing and the test\output file on the remote machine ..duh!  Just to be clear I'll need to have a c:\test folder on each machine so it saves output on the remote machine?

Comment: @NorrinRad: Its local only

Comment: @RanadipDutta Thanks guys :)

Comment: @NorrinRad: Not an issue buddy. As long as it meets your requirement